# Interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not validator.ValidationErrors

Tags: validation, go, types, type-conversion

I am trying to create a CRUD and validating my request body using a Go library called [validator][1]

Validation Code sample:

```
func (v *Validation) Validate(i interface{}) ValidationErrors {
    errs := v.validate.Struct(i).(validator.ValidationErrors) // panic originates here

    if len(errs) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    var returnErrs []ValidationError
    for _, err := range errs {
        // cast the FieldError into our ValidationError and append to the slice
        ve := ValidationError{err.(validator.FieldError)}
        returnErrs = append(returnErrs, ve)
    }

    return returnErrs
}
```

The above validator works for invalid request body such as invalid ID.

But for a valid body, it initiates a panic

Stack Trace:

```
products-api 2020/07/12 15:15:11 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:33288: interface conversion: error is nil, not validator.ValidationErrors
goroutine 21 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0003b6140)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1772 +0x139
panic(0x93d6c0, 0xc0003845d0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:973 +0x3e3
github.com/AymanArif/golang-microservices/data.(*Validation).Validate(0xc0005a8108, 0x8f3480, 0xc0005aa2c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x203000)
        /home/ayman/Desktop/golang-microservices/data/validation.go:70 +0x211

interface conversion: interface conversion: error is nil, not validator.ValidationErrors
```

Create REST Logic:

```
func (p *Products) Create(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    prod := r.Context().Value(KeyProduct{}).(data.Product) // Panic originate here. Check below for struct definiton

    p.l.Printf("[DEBUG] Inserting product: %#v\n", prod)
    data.AddProduct(prod)
}

// data.Product
type Product struct {

    ID int `json:"id"` // Unique identifier for the product

    Name string `json:"name" validate:"required"`

    Description string `json:"description"`

    SKU string `json:"sku" validate:"sku"`
}
```

How can I do error handling for correct requests?
[1]: https://github.com/go-playground/validator

Answer (score 2):

The error you got is eloquent:

`interface conversion: interface {} is *data.Product, not data.Product`

The line `r.Context().Value(KeyProduct{})` returns an interface type `interface{}`, which, the error tells you, is holding a value of concrete type `*data.Product` (*pointer* to `data.Product`)

Instead, you are attempting to convert it to a `data.Product`, without checking whether the conversion is valid.

Replace the line with:

```
prod := r.Context().Value(KeyProduct{}).(*data.Product)
```

You might want to read the Go Tour about [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15).

---

After your update, the error you have now is still the same kind of issue:

`interface conversion: error is nil, not validator.ValidationErrors`

With the expression `err.(validator.FieldError)` you are attempting to convert `err` to a `validator.FieldError` when `err` is in fact `nil`.

The previous check `len(errs) == 0` is only verifying that `errs` length is not zero, but the slice might be of non-zero length *and* contain `nil` values.

You can instead **test** the type assertion:

```
if fe, ok := err.(validator.FieldError); ok {
    ve := ValidationError{fe}
    returnErrs = append(returnErrs, ve)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you re write the Validate function to something like this it should work. Type assertion needs to be checked for errs & err

```
func (v *Validation) Validate(i interface{}) ValidationErrors {
var returnErrs []ValidationError

if errs, ok := v.validate.Struct(i).(validator.ValidationErrors); ok {

    if errs != nil {
        for _, err := range errs {
            if fe, ok := err.(validator.FieldError); ok {
                ve := ValidationError{fe}
                returnErrs = append(returnErrs, ve)
            }
        }
    }
}

return returnErrs
```

}